# I can't add facebook sdk to my android project while using "is check" library

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I have an Android project.AM trying to integrate it with facebook ..i cannot  import libraries to my project . When i am adding the facebook SDK it will setup iinitially but if again checked it shows an error that is "red cross "in project reference..how can i solve this problem?? can any one help me please ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your facebook library to same folder where your project located. And then link it again and check. it will work.

Comment: please accept the answer, if you found its useful, so others can take benefit of it.

Comment: Actually it's not necessary to both projects are in the same folder. But, it is necessary to both projects are in the same drive (same partition).